# Does Google give back its former PageRank to a page that returned 301 during some time

Tags: pagerank

I made a terrible mistake.

2 monthes ago, I put a 301 permanent redirect on a PHP page that displays many old pages of my website.

But those pages were highly SEO friendly and had a good PageRank.

Today I removed the 301 redirect.

Will these pages get back their old PageRank ? Or will it be reset ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Google still finds those pages interesting, then yes you will recover your rankings. However, since these page were not ranked anymore, others may have replaced them and user may have found them more interesting in the mean time. There may also have been ranking algorithms modifications impacting your pages.